# Yeoman custom generator - directory copy produces 'Maximum call stack exceeded' at chalk.js

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have created a custom Yeoman generator, and in it I want to perform a copy of the *wordpress* directory (which is the WordPress installation directory) that is located in the generator's *templates* directory.

In the *index.js* file I call for the directory copy with the following:

`this.directory('wordpress', 'app');`

During the running of this generator it errors out with the following:

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/chalk/chalk.js:0
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 'use strict';
^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

To test, I swapped the *wordpress* directory with a different, smaller directory structure and that worked with no errors. I then tried the above with both Joomla and Drupal directories (both very large directories like *wordpress*), both producing the same error at *chalk.js*.

It therefore seems like in copying large directories with the `directory()` method produces the error.

Is this a bug or is there something I can do to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

While this might not be the best answer (I am still searching for a bug, before I ditch Yeoman entirely) I found an issue (rant) on github here: 
https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/250

The problem doesn't seem to be from Chalk.js (https://github.com/sindresorhus/chalk/issues/4) but the generator itself.

Hope this helps someone.

EDIT 1:
"...and turns out increasing memory for my virtual machine running Ubuntu helped." via (https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/396)